# Passing Data received in one html page to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have variables that I acquire in one html page, such as a UserName or a url or something. And in another html page I have input boxes for these variables and I want to autocomplete them by sending the data from the first html page to the input boxes in the second one. Can anyone indicate to me how I can achieve this?

Comment: possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216536/what-is-the-best-practice-for-passing-variables-from-one-html-page-to-another?rq=1

Comment: in PHP or in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

**You should use $_SESSION variable in php.** OR you can use sessionStorage of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to create the equivalent collection for use by other JS code:

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var querystring = [ ];
var qs = location.search;
if ( qs.length > 1 )
{
    qs = qs.substring(1); // skip past the ?
    var pairs = qs.split( /\&/g ); // get all the name=value pairst
    for ( var p = 0; p < pairs.length )
    {
        var pair = pairs[p];
        querystring[ pair[0] ] = unescape( pair[1].replace(/\+/g," ");
    }
}
</script>
```

Then, anyplace in your page where in ASP code you might use

Code:

`var foo = Request.QueryString("foo");`

you instead simply do

Code:
    `var foo = querystring["foo"];`

CAUTION: "foo" will be case sensitive, unlike in ASP. If you wish, you could replace
Code:

```
querystring[ pair[0] ] = unescape( pair[1].replace(/\+/g," ");
```

with
        `querystring[ pair[0].toLowerCase() ] = unescape( pair[1].replace(/\+/g," ");`

and then always use lower case names ("foo" in place of "Foo" or "FOO") when finding values.

Untested, though I have used this same code before. If there's a goof, it's just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery for that. Assuming you are not using any server side code.

Pass the value as a param to the next page.

Like `myurl?param=xyz`

Then you can get the value in the next page like this,

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831030/how-to-get-get-request-parameters-in-javascript) and [sourcecode](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser/blob/master/jquery.url.js)

`var xyz = jQuery.url.param("param_in_url");`

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? 
So if I go - 
var xyz = "matt@example.com"; 
var url = 'http://caregap2.appspot.com/myurl?param=xyz';
location.href = url;
Then in my next page : 
var xyz = jQuery.url.param("http://caregap2.appspot.com/myurl?param=xyz"); Is that correct?

Comment: I think it was a typo. It should be like var url = 'caregap2.appspot.com/myurl?param='+xyz;

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use php session .store that variable in session and get them in any page.or if you are calling that page from the page where u have values say username call like

```
<a href="nextpage.php?username='ur value'">next page </a>
```